# Send mail using mail() function in PHP , XAMPP on LOCALHOST smtp GMAIL

Tags: php, yii, smtp, sendmail, tcpdf

I do have to send some attchments with chunk_splits so i have to use simple mail function can not use other things like PHPMAILER, swiftMAILER,

My Current Settings  PHP.ini

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587

sendmail_from=xyz@gmail.com

sendmail_path = "\"D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

sendmial settings

```
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
auth_username=xyz@gmail.com
auth_password=xyz
```

are the settings correct ... i am able to send via YiiMail extension.. but becuase of some attachments i have to add so.. i can not do with that..

**IN MAIL I HAVE TO DO THIS SO I CAN NOT USE OTHER THINGS LIKE SWIFT/PHP MAILER**

**$pdf is TCPDF OBJECT i am attaching pdf on the go not saving on the local disk**

```
    $_SESSION['pdf'] = $pdf->Output("order_receipt.pdf", "S");  

    $attachment[0] = chunk_split(base64_encode($_SESSION['pdf']));

    $headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $lable[0] . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
    $headers .= $attachment[0] . $eol . $eol;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHPMAILER supports chunksplit itself
configure PHPMAILER and try

`$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);`

Comment: i do have to add file which is not located on disk... i have to attach pdf file which is got generated from TCPDF ... so i do not have saved that file to my disk... in just add it as base64 data